MATLAB Programmatic App Fcn Callback not working
I am attempting to create a MATLAB app programmatically to have it be more organized. As such I have split up code into different files based on what it does, I have one file to initialize the buttons on the screen. When I attempt to build a function callback for a button I seem to successfully build it. No errors are shown in the terminal, however I get an audible Windows Error noise and the callback action is not triggered. Here is my code:
function obj = selectLoad( grid )           
    %Create file load 1
    obj.fileLoad1 = uibutton(grid, 'push');
    obj.fileLoad1.FontSize = 36;
    obj.fileLoad1.Layout.Row = [8 9];
    obj.fileLoad1.Layout.Column = 1;
    obj.fileLoad1.Text = 'Load 1';
    obj.fileLoad1.ButtonPushedFcn = {@fileLoad1Callback}; 
end
function fileLoad1Callback(src, event)
    fileLoad1.Text = 'Ice Cream';
end

grid here is an argument I pass from my main initilization file that has the uigridlayout for the entire app.
No error code is present so it is very difficult for me diagnose the issue.

Your callback fileLoad1Callback doesn't know anything about the variables in selectLoad. While you can assign characters to a struct fileLoad1.Text it doesn't do anything to your button. Inside fileLoad1Callback just replace fileLoad1.Text with src (which is your button object) and it should work.

Use the debugger. Set a breakpoint in your callback function, then you can see what is going on inside it. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html
